# PT rule in .htaccess in subdirectory that will be processed in .htaccess for parent directory

Tags: mod-rewrite, apache2

I have a PHP project that exposes its API under `/api/public/(xyz)`. The http root directory has `.htacces`s file that rewrites those requests to be processed by `index.php`.

For reason not relevant here, we want to expoze (xyz) methods under `/services(xyz)`.

My very naive approach was to create `services` subdirectory and `.htaccess` file with the following content:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /api/public/$1 [PT]
```

My idea was, that request to `/services/(xyz)` will be rewrited to `/api/public/(xyz)` and handled internall as if the second URL was invoked. However, it doesn't seem to work. Apache logs 404 for the request.

What did I get wrong here?

Please note, it's not the problem with the rule syntax itself, I'm able to get static resource. The problem is, that after rewriting, I get the URL that would be rewrited by other rules, that are in the other file. How the rules are flowing through multiple files is something that is not covered by the canonical question...

Comment: @JennyD Thank you for the link, it is nicely written documentation, but it still gives me now idea how are the rules from multiple files (like in my case) chained...

Comment: Is it Apache generating the 404, or your API? There are some oddities with the way you are doing this, but it should still "work". Please post the `.htaccess` file from the document root (that ultimately routes the request to `index.php`). Do you have any other `.htaccess` files?

Comment: It does, however, tell you how to turn on debug output, which is how you find what happens.